# Wordpress multisites advice needed on different booking engines

Tags: wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages, multisite

I'm facing a bit of a challenge with finding a solution for my WordPress website.
I want to incorporate three different booking engines: one for coworking space, one for events, and one for services. The problem is that I can find all three engines separately, each designed for a different theme.

Now, I'm wondering if using WordPress Multisite could be the answer. The idea is to have three subdomains, each hosting one of the booking engines, while keeping the main domain as the landing page. So, it would look like this:

1. Coworking space booking engine at sub1.domain.com
2. Events booking engine at sub2.domain.com
3. Services booking engine at sub3.domain.com

The main domain would be domain.com.

My understanding is that with WordPress Multisite, users would be able to stay logged in across all four domains (the main domain and the three subdomains). This means they won't need to log in separately on each site. Additionally, I hope to see the receipts from all three domains in a single admin panel for easier management.

Could you please help me understand how WordPress Multisite would be beneficial in this situation and if it would indeed meet my requirements?

Something super important for me to know is how would the user back end look for each user when they log on each of the individual domains?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are describing sounds workable with multisite, if I'm understanding right.
You may need to assign users the Super Admin role or some custom pared down version of it in order for them to be able to access the backend of any *.domain.com subsites using a single login. Otherwise, default behavior is that users need to have a role on each sub1.domain.com, sub2.domain.com, etc. in order to access the backend.

It would help to have more context to understand what you mean by "how would the user back end look for each user when they log on each of the individual domains?"

The backend will look like an admin dashboard with whatever options as determined by their capabilities on that (sub)site, unless they are a super admin, then it should be pretty consistent view.
By default, the backend display will be determined by whatever theme/plugin options are exposed on current domain/subdomain.

You could always create a plugin( e.g. All-Reciepts-Dash ) that presents a uniform backend to users logged in on blog id 1( i.e. the main domain.com site ) or any blog.
Check out WordPress DevHub Documentation on Multisite Network Administration https://wordpress.org/documentation/article/multisite-network-administration/

Comment: Thank you so much for your kind reply. So based on what you said, each subdomain can have its own theme and plugins? Can the multi site also work on totally different domains like domainA.com, domainB.com, domainC.com ?

Comment: Yes! subsites could be setup as subdomains - domain.com, B.domain.com, C.domain.com subdirctories - domain.com, domain.com/B, domain.com/C or custom domains - domainA.com, domainB.com, domainC.com Which is how I setup my own site and those listed on mannycrafts.com/about . All sites sit on the same server. Plugins & themes could also be "network" activated if you want them to be active on all sites using wpcli --network flag. There should be decent documentation for each scenario. You may just need to tweak your Apache,Nginx, and other server config and DNS settings to make it work.

Comment: To be honest, I find WordPress's official documentation lacking when it comes to multisite's many options and capabilities. but don't take this to mean a lack of support. Multisite is very widely used - https://wptavern.com/wordpress-multisite-is-still-a-valuable-and-often-necessary-tool

Luckily, there are a wealth of introductory articles on multisite on hosting and SAAS platforms.
Most of the principles will apply to WordPress in general, not just the platform.
E.g. -
https://docs.pantheon.io/guides/multisite/considerations/
https://wpengine.com/support/what-is-wordpress-multisite/